# Grizzly maxPendingBytes property ignored

Tags: java, out-of-memory, grizzly

I'm developing a project using Grizzly 2.3.22 with its Websocket support. Everything was OK until OOM happened. Looking through the dump I found that all the memory was eaten up by a single `org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOConnection` holding a huge (1,5GB) write queue. I guess one of the client developers was debugging their connected application and stopped on a breakpoint for a long time. Anyway, this can easily happen if a client has a very slow connection - my server should be ready for that.

In the [Grizzly documentation](https://grizzly.java.net/httpserverframework.html#/HTTP_Server_Configuration) I found the **maxPendingBytes** property, which seem like a solution, at least for now. But I cannot get it to work at all. I set log level to ALL for `AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter`, connect with the client, put it on hold and observe how the server's queue grows like this:

```
TRACE 2016-07-05 21:02:26.330 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] o.g.g.n.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter - AsyncQueueWriter.write connection=TCPNIOConnection{localSocketAddress={/127.0.0.1:8445}, peerSocketAddress={/127.0.0.1:56185}}, record=org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.AsyncWriteQueueRecord@1e35bafb, directWrite=false, size=165, isUncountable=false, bytesToReserve=165, pendingBytes=16170
TRACE 2016-07-05 21:02:26.368 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] o.g.g.n.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter - AsyncQueueWriter.write connection=TCPNIOConnection{localSocketAddress={/127.0.0.1:8445}, peerSocketAddress={/127.0.0.1:56185}}, record=org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.AsyncWriteQueueRecord@3d6e05dd, directWrite=false, size=165, isUncountable=false, bytesToReserve=165, pendingBytes=16335
...
```

When I set `maxPendingBytes=10000` I expect an exception thrown when the `pendingBytes` from the log above becomes larger than 10000, but it doesn't happen.

Moreover, I tried debugging the server with the Grizzly's source code, and found that while the property's value does get assigned to the `NIOConnection.maxAsyncWriteQueueSize` field, the `AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.canWrite(...)` method - the only place where the field seems to be used - is never called.

I'm at a loss. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The websocket code doesn't currently leverage this functionality.  I would recommend logging a bug so we can track and address.

Comment: @rlubke thanks, I will file a bug. And while it's not addressed, are there any other solutions to the described problem that I'm missing?

Comment: @rlubke [link](https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1841) to the bug

Comment: I'm thinking of possible solutions that wouldn't require a lot of custom code.  I will follow up on the issue.

Comment: @rlubke thank you, looking forward to it